# Need help removing text and replacing xlm via XLST

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am completely stuck.  I am trying to use XLST to find/replace portions of my xml output file.  I really don't even have starting point.  I've tried using Altova DiffDog to automatically generate my xlst because I don't have a firm grasp on how to write it myself.

This is my current xml output file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<BB:Report_Data xmlns:BB="urn:com.playdate.report/Report-Outbound">
   <BB:Report_Entry>
      <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.employeeId>1234567</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.employeeId>
      <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.bmbId>9280136270</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.bmbId>
      <BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
         <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>1010</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
         <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>0</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>
         <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>2012-07-05</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>2012-07-05</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>
      </BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
         <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>1014</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
         <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>96</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>
         <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>2012-07-05</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>2012-07-05</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>
      </BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.totalDaysService>1459</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.totalDaysService>
   </BB:Report_Entry>
</BB:Report_Data>
```

This is what I need it to look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<BB:Report_Data xmlns:BB="urn:com.playdate.report/Report-Outbound">
   <leaveBalanceTotal>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.employeeId>1234567</leaveBalanceTotal.employeeId>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.bmbId>9280136270</leaveBalanceTotal.bmbId>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>1010</leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>0</leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>2012-07-05</leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>2012-07-05</leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>1014</leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>96</leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>2012-07-05</leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>2012-07-05</leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.totalDaysService>1459</leaveBalanceTotal.totalDaysService>
   </leaveBalanceTotal>
</BB:Report_Data>
```

Essentially I am trying to remove all occurrences of the following:

1. BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker
2. /BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker
3. BB:

And I need to replace Report_Entry with leaveBalanceTotal.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another XSLT 1.0 option. This one will also retain any attributes the data might have.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:BB="urn:com.playdate.report/Report-Outbound" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="BB">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="comment()|processing-instruction()|@*">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="BB:Report_Data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="BB:Report_Entry">
        <leaveBalanceTotal>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </leaveBalanceTotal>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<BB:Report_Data xmlns:BB="urn:com.playdate.report/Report-Outbound">
   <leaveBalanceTotal>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.employeeId>1234567</leaveBalanceTotal.employeeId>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.bmbId>9280136270</leaveBalanceTotal.bmbId>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>1010</leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>0</leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>2012-07-05</leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>2012-07-05</leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>1014</leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>96</leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>2012-07-05</leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>2012-07-05</leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>
      <leaveBalanceTotal.totalDaysService>1459</leaveBalanceTotal.totalDaysService>
   </leaveBalanceTotal>
</BB:Report_Data>
```

Comment: The xsl:apply-templates under your first template is a pointless waste. These node types can never have children.

Comment: @DevNull: The statement that comments and PI "do have children" is completely wrong. The only two node-types that can have children are element and document node.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - Yes you and SeanB.Durkin are correct. Not sure what I was thinking there for a moment. I am going to delete the comment.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin - Removed the pointless waste of an `xsl:apply-templates`.

Answer (score 0):

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:BB="urn:com.playdate.report/Report-Outbound"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Template: copies everything as-is -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Remove BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker elements -->
  <!-- right away, but process their children -->
  <xsl:template match="BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker" priority="2">
    <xsl:apply-templates /> 
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Replace BB:Report_Entry elements with leaveBalanceTotal ones -->
  <xsl:template match="BB:Report_Entry">
    <leaveBalanceTotal>
      <xsl:apply-templates />   
    </leaveBalanceTotal>    
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Remove BB namespace from descendent elements -->
  <xsl:template match="BB:Report_Entry/* | 
      BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />   
    </xsl:element>  
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the provided XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BB:Report_Data xmlns:BB="urn:com.playdate.report/Report-Outbound">
  <BB:Report_Entry>
    <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.employeeId>1234567</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.employeeId>
    <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.bmbId>9280136270</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.bmbId>
    <BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>1010</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>0</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>
      <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>2012-07-05</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>2012-07-05</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>
    </BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
    <BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>1014</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>96</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>
      <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>2012-07-05</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>2012-07-05</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>
    </BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
    <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.totalDaysService>1459</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.totalDaysService>
  </BB:Report_Entry>
</BB:Report_Data>
```

**...the expected result is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BB:Report_Data xmlns:BB="urn:com.playdate.report/Report-Outbound">
  <leaveBalanceTotal>
    <leaveBalanceTotal.employeeId>1234567</leaveBalanceTotal.employeeId>
    <leaveBalanceTotal.bmbId>9280136270</leaveBalanceTotal.bmbId>
    <leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>1010</leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
    <leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>0</leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>
    <leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>2012-07-05</leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
    <leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>2012-07-05</leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>
    <leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>1014</leaveBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
    <leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>96</leaveBalanceTotal.balanceAmount>
    <leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>2012-07-05</leaveBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
    <leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>2012-07-05</leaveBalanceTotal.lastPayEndDate>
    <leaveBalanceTotal.totalDaysService>1459</leaveBalanceTotal.totalDaysService>
  </leaveBalanceTotal>
</BB:Report_Data>
```

Hope that helps! Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: You've neglected to copy attributes in your last 3 templates. Unless the OP specifies otherwise, it would be a better solution to assume that they might be there. Also match expression "node()|@*" is less efficient that "@*|node()" because of sorting. Also better to use local-name() rather than local-name(.) .

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin - thanks for your comments; much appreciated. I didn't include attributes because the OP's original question did not include them. I try to answer the specific question, rather than assume something that isn't explicitly stated.